# Problems with adding images to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I push submit button in _form, Image should be created and linked to the user, but something went wrong. I use the same Image model for Ads and there almost the same code works right. Maybe the problem can somehow be connected with the inconsistency of devise user controllers and my user controller?

**Users controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.images.build
  end

  def edit
    authorize! :update, @user
    @user.images.build
  end

  def create
   @user = current_user
   respond_to do |format|
     if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to board_url }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
     else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
     end
   end
 end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
   if @user.update(user_params)
     format.html { redirect_to board_url }
     format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
   else
     format.html { render :edit }
     format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
   end
  end
end

def destroy
  authorize! :update, @user
  @user.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to board_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, images_attributes: [:id, :name])
  end
end
```

**_form**

```
<%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |form| %>
 <%= form.fields_for :images do |image|  %>
  <div class="image_fields">
   <div class="field">
    <%= image.label t('.img_name') %><br>
    <%= image.text_field :name %>
   </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>

 <div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

**class Image**

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :ad
 belongs_to :user
 validates :name, presence: true
 ...
```

**class User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ads
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :images,
                                reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? },
                                allow_destroy: true

   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

**Migrations**

```
class AddUserIdToImages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
   def change
     add_column :images, :user_id, :integer
   end
end

class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
   def change
     create_table :images do |t|
       t.string :name
       t.references :ad, foreign_key: true

       t.timestamps
     end
   end 
end
```

Comment: you tried to use polymorphism on your model?
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide error message and backtrace.

I assume it is because "ad" reference is blank for the user.
And according to your code:

```
t.references :ad, foreign_key: true
```

So I think the issue is in database constraint
And the simplest solution is to change it to

```
add_column :images, :ad_id, :integer
```

Without foreign key.

Or for your case, you can add [polimorhic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Also, a question not related to the topic, but want to ask about

```
respond_to do |format|
 if @user.save
  format.html { redirect_to board_url }
  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
 else
  format.html { render :new }
  format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
 end
end
```

Why are you saving inside `respond_to` method?
So in rails depth, there is a method:

```
def respond_to(&block)
  ...
  block.call
  ...
end
```

And your `@user.save` will be called there. Are you sure you want it?